# Simple data entry interface (Scaffolding) to SQL Server without having to code it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, csv, sql-server-2008-r2, data-entry

I've got a .Net project where we're using an ActiveRecords scaffolding interface for simple data entry.  Being quick and easy to setup, it is proving time consuming for the data entry folks.  Rather than coding an entire UI for this, what are some recommended applications that I can connect to the DB that give write permission control along with some of the ActiveRecord type of relationships (auto-generating dropdowns for FK's, etc.)?  Even some CSV upload capability would be nice.

I'm looking for a canned, preferably opensource/freeware solution.  However, I also think that some Telerik options (but requiring some coding) may fit the bill.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sifting through the available packages on WebMatrix, I found [SQLCMS](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/sqlcms.aspx) by [DeveloperInABox](http://www.developerinabox.com), which gives me the ability to administer privileges to specific users for data entry.  Perfect.

A little nicer scaffolding UI.  That comes equipped with a panel-like interface for each table.  It does add INSERT and UPDATE sprocs to the db for each table.

Although it doesn't offer a CSV upload, it does offer CSV exports and some nice admin-related settings, along with a windowed/paneled UI.